# Facebook OG tags and wrong scrape

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I'm having issues trying to get facebook to read the OG tags or the source code in general

URL: http://fitbrokers.cz/clanky/jake-vas-cekaji-vydaje-pri-cerpani-hypoteky

If you look at the source code there are some things e.g.:

```
<title>Jaké vás čekají výdaje při čerpání hypotéky? | FitBrokers</title>
```

...

```
<meta name="description" content="Jaké vás čekají výdaje při pořízení nemovitosti na hypotéku? A jak vysokou částku je možné od banky získat? To se dozvíte v dnešním článku. ">
```

...

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Jaké vás čekají výdaje při pořízení nemovitosti na hypotéku? A jak vysokou částku je možné od banky získat? To se dozvíte v dnešním článku. " />
```

...

```
<h1>Články</h1>
    <p><a href="http://fitbrokers.cz/clanky">Články</a> &nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp; Jaké vás čekají výdaje při čerpání hypotéky?</p>
```

...

```
<h1>Jaké vás čekají výdaje při čerpání hypotéky?</h1>
```

What facebook sees through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/:

```
<title>FitBrokers | Jsme pravou rukou makléře</title>
```

...

```
<meta name="description" content="Zde můžete sledovat zajímavosti a aktuality z oblasti financí nebo z naší společnosti FitBrokers, s.r.o. Získáte tak užitečné informace ohledně hypoték, spotřebitelských úvěrů, stavebního spoření a mnoho dalšího, co se týká finančního trhu nebo FitBrokers, s.r.o.">
```

...

Doesn't see the OG tags whatsoever and the second H1 is empty like the slug in the url was wrong - which is not.

Comment: Then you are not sending the right data to Facebook

Comment: @WizKid what do you mean? I'm providing facebook only the url and it's not reading the source code right? Or not? Thanks

Comment: Yes you give Facebook the URL. Facebook then do a request that URL to get the data. So if Facebook have the wrong data then that is because you returned the wrong data when Facebook did a request to that URL.